# The Console.logs of an Electron app runned by gulp are not shown

Tags: node.js, gulp, electron

I'm starting to work with gulp. I have electron app that is invoked by a gulp process. The thing is that I wan't to be able to see the console.logs of the main.js process into the console where the gulp command was executed.

I'm able to see the console.logs of all the render processes in the dev tools.

My gulpfile is:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  browserify = require('gulp-browserify'),
  concatCss = require('gulp-concat-css'),
  run = require('gulp-run');

var src = './process',
  app = './app';

gulp.task('js', function () {
  return gulp.src(src + '/js/render.js')
    .pipe(browserify({
      transform: 'reactify',
      extensions: 'browserify-css',
      debug: true
    }))
    .on('error', function (err) {
      console.error('Error!', err.message);
    })
    .pipe(gulp.dest(app + '/js'));
});

gulp.task('html', function () {
  gulp.src(src + '/**/*.html');
});

gulp.task('css', function () {
  gulp.src(src + '/css/*.css')
    .pipe(concatCss('app.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(app + '/css'));
});

gulp.task('fonts', function () {
  gulp.src('node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts/**/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest(app + '/fonts'));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['serve'], function () {
  gulp.watch(src + '/js/**/*', ['js']);
  gulp.watch(src + '/css/**/*.css', ['css']);
  gulp.watch([app + '/**/*.html'], ['html']);
});


gulp.task('serve', ['html', 'js', 'css'], function () {
  run('electron app/main.js').exec();
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch', 'fonts', 'serve']);
```

Any idea of what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `verbosity` option for gulp-run could be what you are looking for. It defaults to `2`, which means that the output from electron just gets buffered and printed **after** you quit the app. Setting it to `3` should print your console.logs as soon as they come in.

```
gulp.task('serve', ['html', 'js', 'css'], function () {
    run('electron app/main.js', {verbosity: 3}).exec();
});
```